# No attribute error even when the attribute is set

Tags: python, twisted

So I have a class that extends two classes deep, here is it's definition and `__init__()`:

```
class ProspectEventSocketProtocol(ChannelEventSocketProtocol):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProspectEventSocketProtocol, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.channel_info = None

        self.rep_uuid = None
        self.manual_dial = None
        self.datetime_setup = timezone.now()
        self.datetime_answered = None
        self.defer_until_answered = defer.Deferred()
        self.defer_until_originated = defer.Deferred()
        self.defer_until_finished = defer.Deferred()
```

The definition and `__init__()` for the ChannelEventSocketProtocol is here:

```
class ChannelEventSocketProtocol(Freeswitch):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.channel_driver = None
        self.uuid = kwargs.pop('uuid', str(uuid4()))
        self._call_driver = kwargs.pop('call_driver', None)
        super(ChannelEventSocketProtocol, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And the definition and `__init__()` for the Freeswitch class is here:

```
class Freeswitch(client.EventSocketProtocol, TwistedLoggingMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.jobs = {}
        self.defer_until_authenticated = defer.Deferred() # This is the problem
        client.EventSocketProtocol.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        TwistedLoggingMixin.__init__(self)
```

Even though I know that this is running and the defer_until_authenticated is being set as well as it's `callback` and `errback`, when I call this:

```
live_call = yield self._create_client_dial_live_call(client_dial.cid, client_dial.campaign)
pchannel = yield self.realm.get_or_create_channel_driver(live_call.uuid, 'prospect')
# ...
client_dial.prospect_channel = pchannel
yield pchannel.freeswitch_protocol.defer_until_authenticated # This is the problem here!
```

I get the error:

```
type object 'ProspectEventSocketProtocol' has no attribute 'defer_until_authenticated'
```

I have no idea why I can't get the attribute again. I know it is being set, but I have no idea where it goes... or what happens to it. I've searched the error and I have no idea what is happening in this spot.

Just for reference, here are the `_create_client_dial_live_call()` and `get_or_create_channel_driver()` functions:

```
def _create_client_dial_live_call():
    # ...
    p, created = Prospect.objects.get_or_create_client_dial_prospect(campaign, cid_num)
    # ...
    live_call = LiveCall(prospect=p, campaign=campaign.slug)
    live_call.channel_vars_dict = chan_vars
    live_call.save()
    # ...

def get_or_create_channel_driver()
    # The code is kind of confusing with even more context, 
    # it basically either gets the existing ProspectChannel
    # object or creates a new one and then returns it.
```

Comment: Try editing `ProspectEventSocketProtocol` to look something like [this](http://pastebin.com/J616arfy) and post the output (you may have to try the link several times; Pastebin seems to be a tad overloaded :).

Comment: The same error is still there and it didn't print anything out, so it doesn't look like any attribute is being deleted. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something somewhere is forgetting to instantiate a class.

The error is not telling you that an instance of the class `ProspectEventSocketProtocol` has no attribute `defer_until_authenticated`.  It's telling you that the class `ProspectEventSocketProtocol` itself has no such attribute.

In other words, you are quite probably writing something like

```
pchannel.freeswitch_protocol = ProspectEventSocketProtocol
```

when you want

```
pchannel.freeswitch_protocol = ProspectEventSocketProtocol(...)
```

instead.

Here's a quick demo script that reproduces the error message you are seeing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.arg = "1234"


correct = Test()
print(correct.arg)

wrong = Test
print(wrong.arg)
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
1234
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./type_object_error.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(wrong.arg)
AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'arg'
```